# How to structure an object whose time field depends upon another objects time field?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, database-design

Basically there's an Appointment model, along with an Available_Hours model.

The Appointment model is used by the customers. The Available_Hours is used by the employees to set their hours for a given day, so each of these objects is for a given day.

The Appointment object time field needs to be dependent on the Available_Hours object. So that when the customer creates an appointment there will be a dropdown select field that displays all of the available hours employees have.

I am new to working with databases.

Also, say the Available_Hours is 8 hours long. An appointment will only take 2 of those hours, so the other unused hours should remain in that dropdown select customers used to set an appointments time.

```
class AvailableHours(models.Model):
"""Hours Employee Has Available For That Day"""
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
work_date = models.DateField()
start_work_time = models.TimeField()
end_work_time = models.TimeField()

class Appointment(models.Model):
"""Appointment Information"""
owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date = models.DateField()
time = models.TimeField()
```